# How can I downgrade CentOS 6.5 to CentOS 6.3 on VirtualBox 4.3.10

Tags: virtualbox, centos6, downgrade

I ran the yum on CentOS 6.3, so that it turned into another kernel CentOS 6.5. After restart of the VirtualBox I couldn't anymore run neither the old nor the new OS. Do you know a way to downgrade to CentOS 6.3? How can I get into the machine with SSH without knowing it's IP address?

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, you require a DNS service and maybe you have it; you can check the settings of your DHCP server where list the hostname of your virtual machine. Assuming that you are in a scenario where you have a DHCP and DNS server normally called "Modem Router" and do require SSH Connection temporarily.

Now the first question, I have a lot to say, but to my knowledge, it is difficult to make a "downgrade" on linux on all packages that could be updated, if it is only the kernel and it is another matter. I suggest: 
https://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-cg-en-7.2/buildkernel-bootloader.html